# rolling a dice multiple times: when the distribution is binomial and when it is not

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I suppose we roll a 6-sided dice three times. A probability to to obtain two times number 3 can be framed as binomial because I can define as "p" a probability to obtain 3 and "1-p" the remaining outcomes. But if the question is the probability to obtain twice 3 and once 1, the problem cannot be solved using binomial, because there are more than two potential outcomes (3, 1 and anything else). Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The last question could be answered using the multinomial distribution, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for help!